# Bootstrap tooltip opens and closes repeatedly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap tooltip which I have custom styled. There seems to be an issue with it. Whenever we hover over it, it opens and then immediately closes.

HTML -

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:300px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>A bunch of random text</span><span class="info-circle" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip Text">i</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>A bunch of random text</span><span class="info-circle" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip Text">i</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an inline link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/repulsivestud/2h7jbt9n/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are no longer using the `tooltip-arrow` as the visual arrow you are using the `:before` and `:after` after as the visual arrow.  The problem is that you have made the arrow bigger and made your own triangles.  When you make your css arrow you are using borders.  You have set your top border colors to white and blue to make it seem like the arrow has a border as well.  In doing this you have forgotten that your arrow still has a bottom transparent border and this transparent border is covering up the element that you are hovering over to deploy the tooltip.  So set your `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements for your `.tooltip-arrow` to have a bottom border of none.  Like so:

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  left: -17px;
  top: -5px;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-top-color: #003f6e;
  border-bottom:none;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  left: -15px;
  top: -5px;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  border-bottom:none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue. Would you mind telling me how you analyzed it?

Comment: I just figured there was something getting in the way and many people forget that when making triangles you use borders and always forget about their transparent border widths.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I made a few changes. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/2h7jbt9n/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:30px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>A bunch of random text</span><span class="info-circle" title="YoHo Ho Ho" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">i</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>A bunch of random text</span><span class="info-circle" title="YoHo Ho Ho" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">i</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        container: '.info-circle'
    });
});
```

The issue was with padding for the info-circle. I wrapped it in a container. It doesn't flicker now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but if I change `data-placement` to `top`, it fails. And I need it to be on the top always, sadly

Comment: Sorry but the tool-tip needs to be appended to each `info-circle` class.